# Getting Global Access to URL ID Params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

How do I get global access to the current URL ID params? I'm having trouble getting access to the current URL ID in a child component in React. The ID is needed in order to query a MongoDB database in my `ChecklistTool` component.

Normally, I'd pass the props and get access to `params` that way. However, I'm using Editor.js which is not letting me pass the props as required.

This is my Editor.js component. It has access to params information:

```
     <EditorJs
        instanceRef={(instance) => (instanceRef.current = instance)}
        placeholder="Start typing what's in your head..."
        tools={EDITOR_JS_TOOLS}
        enableReInitialize={true}
        data={data}
      />
```

This is my custom Checklist component which is rendered as a block inside of the Editor.js component. I'm unable to pass the URL params to this component:

```
     <ChecklistTool
        onDataChange={onDataChange}
        readOnly={this.readOnly}
        data={this.data}
        isAdmin={true}
      />
```

This is the file where I'm using React Router:

```
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/document/:id" component={DocumentView}/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Any idea how to get access to the current URL params ID in all required files? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a version of React >= 16.8 then you can use hooks.
Instead of using props to pass the value, React-Router provides a hook called useParams which enables you to access the URL params from within any component (as long as it is wrapped inside the router), which makes it essentially global and accessible from any child without passing as props.

This is how you use it:

First you import useParams

```jsx
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";
```

Then call the hook

```jsx
const params = useParams(); //:id param will be in params.id and so on...
```

If you have tried this approach and did not work for you, let me know more about the kinds of errors you received, if any, and I will look into them.

[React-Router reference for more information about useParams hook.](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tested out useParams and it didn't work for my application and I believe here's why: App.js is the top level file and has the routes (code shown in initial post). The hierarchy is: App.js > DocumentView > DocumentEditor (editor.js component) > ChecklistTool.js. App.js directly references Documentview so useParams works. However, useParams returns undefined for DocumentView and DocumentEditor as they are not directly referenced by react router. Does that make sense? I can clarify further if required.

Comment: All the routes contained inside the <Router> wrapper should be able to access the useParams hook. I'm not sure why it would return undefined... unless no params were passed. How are you calling the route /document/:id ? Through React-Router's <Link> or by other means? Are you sure that id is defined when the route is accessed? Did you try setting id to a constant value and passing it to the path?
You can also try the other hooks useLocation and useHistory, see if they return something or also undefined.

Comment: I believe you are correct. Digging into my code more, this appears to be a broader issue of the checklist tool component not being rendered on the main DOM. Once I figure out how to get it to render on the correct DOM, I think your solution will work. I'll let you know when I can test it!

Comment: Cool. Let me know how it goes. :)